# cannot resolve symbol "CucumberOptions" in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am seeing "cannot resolve CucumberOptions" error in IntelliJ even after adding "cucumber-java" and "cucumber-junit" to my pom.xml

[image]

Answer (score 5):

After spending lot of time, I found the issue with the dependency in pom.xml

You need to add "cucumber-core" in addition to "cucumber-java" and "cucumber-junit"

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I have all three dependencies and I am still struggling with this.  Could it be something else?